# How to reset service between tests in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service

I have a service that is injected into beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $state, $injector, $controller, MyService) {
    var state = $state;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    myService = MyService;
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$state: state, MyService: myService});
}));
```

And I have some tests described with "it":

```
it('test1', function() { 
   var data = ["test"]; 
   ctrl.extract_data(data); 
   expect(myService.get_data()).toEquals("test");
});
```

Now my problem is that I have a shared variable in service (variable data) between the tests and if I run the test with other data (e.g. var data = ["a", "b"]), the variable that is shared in myService will contain a, b and test (that was retrieved from the previous test). Is there a way to "reset" the service content everytime a test is ran?

Comment: Hi there, I thought I had the same problem but apparently, `angular.mock.inject` seems to provide a new instance of the service everytime. Can you create a plunkr to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I am also having the problem that the same instance of a service is used to run different tests. As a workaround I redefined the service with `$provide.service('myService', app.MyService);` in a `beforeEach`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to reset it, but each `it` block don't share anything with other `it` blocks. You could just inject a new controller in each `it` block.

```
it('test1', function() {
   var ctrl; 
   var data = ["test"]; 
   inject(function($controller) {
     ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {$state: state, MyService: myService}
   })
   ctrl.extract_data(data); 
   expect(myService.get_data()).toEquals("test");
});
```

Comment: you could also wrap that functionality in a new function to use it as a shortcut